# Why doesn't Ruby automatically execute to_s?

Tags: ruby, string, metaprogramming

I have an author class:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Defining `to_s` allows me to do `puts Author.first`, but not `puts Author.first.rjust(10)`:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `rjust' for #<Author:0x21eb5d4>
```

Wouldn't it be better if Ruby automatically tried `to_s` before the string method in cases like this? Is there any way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, no, it wouldn't.  I don't want ruby to just say "Hey, maybe this is a string method, let me see if I can run it after running `to_s`" on an arbitrary object.  That being said, there are two solutions to what you want to do:

If you want to say "On any `Author` instance, if someone calls a method that it doesn't have, but that `String` does, then it should magically call `to_s`", then do this:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name
  end

  def method_missing(s, *a)
    x = to_s
    if x.respond_to? s then
      return x.send(s, *a)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to say "`rjust` on anything that isn't a String should mean calling `to_s` first", then:

```
class Object
  def rjust(*a)
    to_s.rjust(*a)
  end
end
```

(Repeat with other methods as desired; note that this allows you to do things like `86.rjust(10)`; whether that's a good thing or not may be a matter of taste)

Comment: That `super.method_missing(s, *a)` is incorrect. It should just be `super`, which calls the superclass's version of the method with the same arguments. In Ruby, super acts like a method rather than a receiver.

Comment: @Chuck: Thanks, fixed.  I did test my code before posting, but was fooled because the action of "super" is to throw an exception - this means that for this particular case, the incorrect syntax worked as expected.  (Since ruby never tries to call "method_missing" on the return value of super)

Answer (score 2):

*Wouldn't it be better if Ruby automatically tried to_s before the string method in cases like this?*

You're heading down a slippery slope by asking for a language to "just do what I mean (most of the time)." While it might make sense in many cases, it's bound to foul things up around the edges. In your case, who's to say that **rjust** isn't a method defined on Author (or one of its superclasses).

Answer (score 2):

Check out ruby's [support for delegation and method forwarding](http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/delegation-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually... there IS a method that would do something vaguely similar to this: `to_str`

However, it still wouldn't be called implicitly for this particular case.  The existence of a `to_str` method in Ruby is effectively equivalent to saying, "Any method that would normally take a String as a parameter may implicitly convert this object to a String by calling the `to_str` method."  Most methods in the standard library will attempt to use this technique to coerce to String, and a lot of 3rd party libraries do as well.

In the example you gave, however, it would be absolutely inappropriate for Ruby to detect that an unhandled message was String-like and convert.  This would lead to all kinds of errors, bugs, and general misbehavior in a lot of non-String related code, especially any of the code out there like Builder that relies on the normal missing method behavior.